# How to make an if-request with jQuerys .haveClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to know how to make a jQuery with the `.haveClass()`. I didn't figure out how it could work yet.

This is my code:

```
function getRightCol(){
           var rc=document.getElementById('right-col');
           var lc=document.getElementById('left-col');
           var cc=document.getElementById('center-col');
           $(rc).addClass('fadeIn animated').removeClass('hidden');
           $(lc).addClass('fadeIn animated');
           $(cc).addClass('fadeIn animated');
           window.setTimeout( function(){
              $(rc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
              $(lc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
              $(cc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
           },1000);
};
```

What I need is, that `lc` and `cc` are only fade in if the right col doesn't exist yet. If right-col exists and the content is just changed, the other cols should not fade in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ with a normal `if` statement.  If you want more info, please consider adding a jsfiddle.net and referencing more of your code.  E.g. where is `rc` defined?

Comment: edited my code, so that it should be understandable now.

Comment: It's called `if statement` or `if condition` and this is such a basic programming feature, that you should read into [some JS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Conditional_Statements), before asking questions here.

Comment: Yes but i did not know exactly how to connect this basic if statement with a jquery method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function getRightCol(){
           var rc=document.getElementById('right-col');
           var lc=document.getElementById('left-col');
           var cc=document.getElementById('center-col');
           if($(rc).hasClass('hidden')){
             $(rc).addClass('fadeIn animated').removeClass('hidden');
             $(lc).addClass('fadeIn animated');
             $(cc).addClass('fadeIn animated');

             window.setTimeout( function(){
                $(rc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
                $(lc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
                $(cc).removeClass('fadeIn animated');
             },1000);
           }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(lc.hasClass("sample")){ 

}
else{

}
```